# How to query a node.js instance what options/flags were set?

Tags: node.js

I'm running a node app inside a container. A number of flags and options are passed to node when it is running and I want to figure out which options made it finally to the script.

I have found the documentation on setting these flags but I can't find anything to get them. **I can query the environment variables**, but what if I have made a typo and it didn't set anything?

### So how can I output somehow the flags an actual node instance is running with?

#### What non-direct methods I have tried so far

1. outputting environment variables with `console.dir(process.env)`: the problem it does not show flags passed from command line
2. Trying to pass a wrong flag: for example passing this `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-hold-spice-size=123` will make node to fail, so at least you know that you can pass flags to node

Comment: [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

Comment: flags != environment variables which is it? flags like --expose-gc etc if you want flags then you can use `console.log(process.execArgv)`, you find most things out by looking in console.log(global)

Answer (score 0):

You can access every environment variable visible to node instance using:

```
console.log(process.env)
```